# How to remove an unwanted line-like disruption with jagged edges in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to plot a function that doesn't have singular points, but the output displays a line-like disruption where the graph appears discontinuous. My code is here, and the output follows.

```
c = 2.78; q = 0.16; x0 = -2;
setting1 = {ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Exclusions -> "Singularities", PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Thick, Red]};
Plot3D[
 -((Sqrt[c/q] (1 - Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))/(
   2 (1 + Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))) + (
  c (1 + Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))/(
  2 Sqrt[c/q] q (1 - Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))
 , {x, -2, 2}, {t, 0.1, 1},
 Evaluate[setting1],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "U", " "},
 PlotLabel -> "U"]
```

[image: Unwanted line-like disruption]

Upon setting `Exclusions` to `'None'` these disruptions disappear. However, singular points then emerge in the form of pillars, which are also visually bad.

[image: Exclusions to 'None']

So my question is, how to avoid these disruptions without showing singular points? I tried to set `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` but it did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function $-\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{c}{q}} \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{c}{q}} (-c
   t+x+\text{x0})\right)}{\tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{c}{q}} (-c
   t+x+\text{x0})\right)-1}$  is singulaer if

`1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (x - c t + x0) == Pi/4 (2 k - 1), Element[k,Integers]`

```
c = 2.78; q = 0.16; x0 = -2;
setting1 = {ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Exclusions -> 
    Table[ 1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (x - c t + x0) == Pi/4 (2 k - 1) , {k, -10, 
      10}]  , PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Thick, Red]};
Plot3D[-((Sqrt[
        c/q] (1 - Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))/(2 (1 + 
         Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))) + (c (1 + 
       Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)]))/(2 Sqrt[
      c/q] q (1 - Tan[1/2 Sqrt[c/q] (-c t + x + x0)])), {x, -2, 
  2}, {t, 0.1, 1}, Evaluate[setting1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "U", " "}, PlotLabel -> "U" 
 ]
```

[image]